# flutter sign up with same account

Tags: firebase, flutter

I'm new to Flutter and I'm trying to learn how to use Flutter+Firebase together so I created an app using those tool. And here is some detail about my app and the problem I've got.

1.User can Sign Up to create an account in Firebase Authentication field.

2.If the user tried to create an account with an email that's already exist in the Firebase Authentication field it will show a dialog (or maybe a snackbar I haven't got to that point yet) that the email is already in use.

so I created an account in Firebase Authentication field (through my app) and it work fine
but then when I tried to create an account with the same email my screen is freezing (mobile emulator screen) and the editor open the file "message_codecs.dart" in line 582

```
if (errorCode is String && (errorMessage == null || errorMessage is String) && !buffer.hasRemaining)
  throw PlatformException(code: errorCode, message: errorMessage as String, details: errorDetails, stacktrace: errorStacktrace);
```

with the red flag saying

```
PlatformException (PlatformException(ERROR_EMAIL_ALREADY_IN_USE, The email address is already in use by another account., null, null))
```

even if I use the `.catchError()` here is my code that trying to catch this error

```
Future<void> registerThread() async {
FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
await firebaseAuth
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: emailString, password: passwordString)
    .then((response) {
  print("Register Successfully for Email: $emailString");
  registerSuccessAlert();
}).catchError((err) {
  String code = err.code;
  String message = err.message;
  print("ERROR : $message CODE: $code");
});
```

}

the following code should catch the error and then printing the error message and error code on my console but it's not printing instead it pop the file "message_codecs.dart" and my emulator screen freeze as I said above, is there anything I missed? please help thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this one ? Just change to `then`less version.

```
Future<void> registerThread() async {
   FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
   try {
        var result = await firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: emailString, password: passwordString);
        print("Register Successfully for Email: $emailString");
        registerSuccessAlert();
   }catch(e){
         String code = err.code;
         String message = err.message;
         print("ERROR : $message CODE: $code");
   }
}

var registerResult = await registerThread();
```

Comment: Hi there thanks for your answer it's worked now. Could you provide me an insight about how your code work but my code above doesn't?